# CSS Centering image in bootstrap responsive div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get an image centered within a a responsive div.

The alignment to the right is correct as the window is wide, but as the window is reduced when the div jumps down to the next level, i wish for the image to appear centered. Currently using several methods i cannot make it move at all from the left.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bluey/Lw8gw/)

**The HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>

<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"> 
    <img>...</img> <!-- the img i am trying to center -->
</div>
```

I have tried
`margin: 0 auto;` on the img, and `relative` on the parent of which does not work.

Alternatively i have tried the assumed method for centering content in bootstrap:

`class="img-responsive center-block"` on the `img`
of which also does not work.

Am i missing something here?

Comment: Yes.  You need to get `text-align: center` applied to that containing div - add `text-center` to your div, then your `margin: 0 auto;` will work.

Comment: Heres the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bluey/SXzpL/ @cale_b

Comment: It absolutely *is* centered in the div it is contained within.  But that div is only 33% of the width of the available space - do you want it to be centered in the full width of the available space? (col-md-4 tells it to use 4 of 12 columns, or 33% of the available space).  Additionally, you have the image set to 100% of the available width, so while it's "centered", it's filling up the majority of the div.

Comment: I would like the img to appear in the center of the available space yes, i thought that when the cell moves down it assumes full width div size. Thats clearly my issue but i am still not entirely sure how to correct that. @cale_b

Comment: Use `col-sm-12 col-xs-12` in your class for that div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i figured it out. I had made a mistake by using the incorrect classes for the responsive grid.

**Changed:**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>

<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"> 
    <img>...</img> <!-- the img i am trying to center -->
</div>
```

**To:**

```
<div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>

<div class="col-md-4"> 
    <img>...</img> <!-- the img i am trying to center -->
</div>
```